# How can I produce livestock in Illyriad?

Tags: illyriad

I've begun playing [Illyriad](http://www.illyriad.co.uk/), and I'd like to produce some livestock for leather.  The obvious place to produce this would be the *Common Ground*.

> The Common Ground is an ancestral
>   right for your citizens to graze their
>   cattle inside the city walls,
>   producing livestock for your City's
>   Saddlemakers and Tanners to turn into
>   useful end products.

But when I try to produce some livestock using the production tab there I get the following message:

> **Unable to start Production!**
>   You do not have the building necessary to produce this item.

What building do I need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to upgrade your Common Ground to level 1 (it starts at level 0) - to begin production of livestock

Comment: That worked, thanks.  It's not very apparently from the in game text though.

Comment: @C.Ross - It would make sense for there to be some production possible from common ground and paddock even if they are at lvl0, I agree, but you could view it as saying that your citizens and soldiers graze their livestock/horses on those plots but the plots don't produce anything for *you* until you build some structure there.